# unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous' & URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'

Tags: c#, web-services, iis

I get this error when consuming a Soap webservice. I've tried many recommendations while googling such as:

```
<security mode="Transport">
       <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="weblogic" />
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>

<security mode="Transport">
       <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>

   <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
       <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
```

the webservice endpoint is unders https and here is my c# code:

```
BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
            basicHttpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;

            CustomerPortTypeClient client = new CustomerPortTypeClient(basicHttpBinding,
                new EndpointAddress("https:......."));
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"].ToString();
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userpwd"].ToString();
            client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["servercertfilepath"].ToString());
```

when i comment the line `basicHttpBinding.Security.Mode =BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;` the returning message changes and i get:
Détails: The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.
Parameter name: via.

any advices or recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those having the same issue. Here is the code used pass the issue:

```
BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            basicHttpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
            basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
            basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None;
            basicHttpBinding.Security.Transport.Realm = "weblogic";
            basicHttpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;
            CustomerPortTypeClient client = new CustomerPortTypeClient(basicHttpBinding,
                new EndpointAddress("https:....."));
            client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["servercertfilepath"].ToString());
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"].ToString();
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userpwd"].ToString();
```